# SQLAlchemy - Traditional and Declarative mapping in many-to-many

Tags: sqlalchemy

According to SQLAlchemy's documentation for many-to-many relationships, the join table is declared using Traditional mappings. The other tables are declared using Declarative mappings.

Why not just one type of mapping, like Declarative? Is that possible in this case?

```
    association_table = Table('association', Base.metadata,
    Column('left_id', Integer, ForeignKey('left.id')),
    Column('right_id', Integer, ForeignKey('right.id'))
)

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'left'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Child",
                    secondary=association_table)

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'right'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's absolutely possible, but the reason people don't typically do it is simply because they usually don't want to use the association table like an object.

It'd look something like:

```
class Left(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'left'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True

class Right(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'right'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class M2MRightLeft(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'm2m_right_left'
    left_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('left.id'), primary_key=True)
    right_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('right.id'), primary_key=True)
```

That being said, I'd generally stick with the traditional mappings for M2M relationships.  Generally, I only use the declarative style if there are additional columns I want to add to the M2M table.

Comment: Thanks. How does that map a bi-directional relationship, though? http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many

Comment: Ah, actually, "secondary" accepts a String, not just a Table object.